# Unexpected rounded UIButton behavior inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, rounded-corners, uistackview

I made a cool custom number pad for user input. It consists of 12 `UIButtons` 3 each inside 4 `UIStackView`s, which are themselves nested inside a parent `UIStackView`. I want the buttons to be round. Desired appearance is like this:

[image]

Here's the code to round the corners:

```
for (UIStackView *subStack in self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews)
{
    for (UIButton *button in subStack.arrangedSubviews)
    {
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
        button.layer.cornerRadius = (button.frame.size.width)/2.0f;
        button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        button.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
        NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld", (long)button.tag);
    }
}
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

The problem is that when I put this code into `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, the buttons look like this:

[image]

The fully rounded buttons don't show up unless I put the code in `viewDidAppear`. But there's a noticeable delay before the circles are rendered.

Anybody have an idea what's causing the strange behavior? I'm wondering if it has to do with the `UIStackViews` themselves, as I've encountered other problems with them.

Using Xcode 7.3.1 and El Capitan 10.11.3

**EDIT**

I tried the suggestion in @Murat Tezyapar's answer below, but the code doesn't get called in viewDidLayoutSubviews, nor in viewWillLayoutSubviews (I figured it was worth a try...). I did some NSLogging and discovered that the buttons reach their proper size (70 pts) only if the code is executed in viewDidAppear. And the circles, as noted above, still render after the buttons themselves, and everything else.

Answer (score 2):

This might occur because your view's frame are not set yet when viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad was triggered. viewDidLayoutSubviews is a good place for it since all constraint are taken in to account and views are resized according to your constraints at this point. It appears you try to access your buttons frame on viewDidLoad and get their initial value (ex:20 px width and height) when it should be 50 px at viewDidLayoutSubviews.

So when you set your corner radius with:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = (button.frame.size.width)/2.0f;
```

you can't get the correct frame width, so you set 10.0 corner radius on a 50 px width button.

Conclusion:

Use viewDidLayoutSubviews if you're using autolayout.

Comment: I'm circularizing views inside a stack view, and with the circularization code in viewWillAppear, was only getting rounded corners, not perfect circles. When I moved the circularization code from viewWillAppear to viewDidLayoutSubviews, the issue was fixed. Thanks for your suggestion!